# How Can I Show A Search Result In A Textbox?

Tags: c#, oledb

I have created a table code and would like to search and retrieve an answer introducing device IMEI in TextBox IMEI und when I click on the search, I want to display the result `code_mck` in the textbox code i want display the result:

```
id  Imei             code_mck
1  356885021519453   830782136
2  356885021519156   948790617
3  356885021518893   715398945
4  356885021518935   567456626
5  359654022104377   557960750
```

Initially I have a typical three-layer architecture and the search method is in the Data Layer.  I have some trouble with my SQL Query:

```
public DataSet recherche(string code)
{
    DataSet ds = null;
    using (OleDbConnection cnn = new OleDbConnection(strConn))
    {
        cnn.Open();
        string Oledb = "SELECT * FROM Code WHERE Imei=@IMEI";
        using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(Oledb, cnn))
        {
            adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IMEI", code);
            ds = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(ds, "Code");
        }
    }
    return ds;
}
```

**Business Logic layer:**

```
namespace unlock2_buisness
{
    public  class code_imei

    public DataSet rechercheduCode(string imei)
    {
        unlockDAL objetDataLayer = new unlockDAL();

        if (imei == "")
            throw new Exception("merci d'indique l'imei de recherche");
        DataSet dt = null;
        dt = objetDataLayer.recherche(imei);
        return dt;
}
```

In my User Layer, the TextBox dedicated for search to display the result in textbox code is not responding, and am not getting the appropriate code by providing the device IMEI as it should be from the table.

```
private void btnrechercheimei_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    imeiLogic.rechercheduCode(txtimei.Text);
    imeiLogic.rechercheduCode(txtcode.Text);
}
```

I will appreciate your support.

Comment: And Could You Please Format Your Title In A Sane Way? It Hurts. Thank You Very Much.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is how you use your BusinesLogic class.

`public DataSet rechercheduCode(string imei)` takes a string as input parameter and returns a DataSet.

When you call the method like this:

```
imeiLogic.rechercheduCode(txtimei.Text);
```

you do provide the input parameter (the value that is in textbox) but you don't store the returned Dataset in a variable.

The dataset wil have  a table called *Code* that will hold the result rows from the query or 0 rows if nothing is found.

Staying as close as possible to your current implementation I suggest this:

```
private void btnrechercheimei_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // call the BLL to get a dataset
    var dataSet = imeiLogic.rechercheduCode(txtimei.Text);
    // get our table in the dataset
    var codeTable = dataSet.Tables["Code"]; // table
    // check if there was a row returned
    if (codeTable.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        var row = codeTable.Rows[0];  // pick the first one
        txtcode.Text = row["code_mck"].ToString();  // update our textbox 
    }    
    // Add handling for 0 rows and/or more than 1 rows returned
}
```